# How to load in font awesome when using node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am using node server as a test enviroment for a chat application I'm building. I can't seem to load in the font awesome library.

To link to the css I use this on the server.js: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

And that works.

But it doesn't work for font awesome.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would verify that your `font-awesome.css` and `/font` folder is updated and no plugins are loading an older version. Could also be your `MIME` types are misconfigured. This page may also be of use to you: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: could I load in the font awesome library with node_modules?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks anyway

Comment: @JonasSH How did you figure it out? What ended up being the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this way ..

1.make sure you kept your font awesome folder inside **/public** folder.

2.Next static path to the **public** folder, also you can try this way without using **path.join**

3.then you can access directly font awesome folder in frond end where you want to use font awesome resources.

[Check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2mRJ.jpg)

There is another way , You can install Bower packaged component can be made up of any type of assets like bootsrap, angular, font awesome and etc.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower

hope this answer will help for you. sorry If my English is not clear.